# New demand generation from available in the form of buckets

Tags: sql, sas, data-integration

I have a requirement where in there are forecasted values of few offices which are linked to one main office.
For example,office 1,office 2, office 3 are linked to mainoffice.Forecasted values are for entire month.Now I need to use some formula to create demand for mainoffice based on its link offices.

```
          1     2    3     4    5                                 28   29    30 
office1   100  200  300  150   120                               100   130   160

office2   200  100  150  200   130                               160   120   100

office3   400  350  200  400   260                               100   130   200
```

now main office in the month
required output -  ((officetotal1+officetotal2+officetotal3)/30)*5

This same value has to be put in the form of 3 buckets for month
i.e 1st 11th and 21st

```
             1                         11                           21
mainoffice1   X                          X                           X
mainoffice2   Y                          Y                           Y
```

Mapping
office       mainoffice
------       ---------
office1      mainoffice1/n

office2      mainoffice1/n

office3      mainoffice2/n

Comment: Please show the data structure that links the three offices to the main office.  Or, do you just want to summarize all the data into one row?

Comment: Its like there is other table which contains the mapping for all the offices and main office.Say office1,office2,office3 - mainoffice1 and office4,office5,office6 - mainoffice2 and so on.I need to demand created for all the mainoffices based on respective offices.Can it be done in sql?

Comment: . . Yes, this can be readily done in SQL, but you need the mapping from the main offices to the other offices.

Comment: I have provided sample example in above comment.Considering the same example,could you guide me accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

You do this with a `join`.  It is something like:

```
proc sql;
    select o.mainoffice, sum(val1) as val1, sum(val2) as val2, . . .
    from forecasts f join
         offices o
         on f.office = o.office
    group by o.mainoffice;
```

The point is to do a `join` to get the main office information and then to do an aggregation for the values you want.

EDIT:

Then you just add together the values that you want:

```
    select o.mainoffice,
           sum(val1 + val2 + . . . val10 + val11) as val1_11,
           . . . 
    from forecasts f join
         offices o
         on f.office = o.office
    group by o.mainoffice;
```

Comment: Gordon,here I do not want to create demand for main office on each day of the month.I want it in interval of 10 days i.e 1st,11th and 21st of the month.So,ideally if the forecasted values of office are stretching on each day in month from 1-30,then my main office will have demand on only 3 days i.e on 1,11,21 based on my formula for demand.Not able to get the logic on how to do this.

Comment: I was exactly trying that,but my requirement is bit different.So,the confusion.The mainoffice demand is created for every 10 days based on the aggregated demand of the linked offices for the month as 5 days demand (sum*5/30).To be clear,say for office1 sum of values in that month is 100,office2 it is 200.Then,the mainoffice 5 days demand for every 10 days is 300*5/30 = 50.Now say,my job ran on 31st and forecasted values for offices for next 30 days,then main office for 1st of that month should be 50,also 11th and 21st also 50.After 10 days,my main office job is run again to create new demand.

Comment: In this case,my main office demand for 1-10 should be firm as 50 only.But when the main office job is  run on 10th eod,11th demand is changed because the linked offices demand job runs daily and forecasts for next 30 days where the values might change.Please let me know if the requirement is clear.Else I'll try to explain more clearly.